# Login with gpg key instead of password

Tags: arch-linux, login, gpg

There is a gpg key on my system that I use to encrypt just about everything. I encrypt my emails with it, some secure files, my passwords, etc. I would like to use this gpg key (which has an associated password) to login to my system on startup.

The reason that I want to do this is because my current setup forces me to type my password on login and then my gpg key password immediately after (because it is used on startup). I would like to bypass having to type two passwords and simply unlock my gpg key on login.

I am running Arch Linux with the default login manager.

Comment: You forgot to add how you want to present the key for authentication. From a USB maybe? If you just want to unlock your key, then maybe your standard keyring is an option. But I don't know if that's a good idea security-wise.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/cruegge/pam-gnupg) could interest you

Comment: @Anonymous that's exactly what I was looking for!